# Update Provider Information from Firebase Auth User (Cloud Functions)

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, google-cloud-functions

I have a user flow as such;

1. Every user signs in anonymously.
2. They then have the option to sign in with social providers (*Facebook, Google, etc...*)
3. I link their social provider with their anonymous user ID. (*successfully implemented*)
4. I then add the provider data to the Firestore Database (*Issue here!*)

I have written the function as;

```
exports.updateUserProvider = functions.auth.user().onUpdate((change, user) => {
    const updatedData = change.after.data()
    console.log(updatedData);
    const uid = user.uid;
    const userRef = admin.firestore().doc(`/users/${uid}`);
    return userRef.update({
        isAnonymous: false,
        displayName: user.displayName,
        email: user.email
    });
});
```

Unfortunately, there is no `.onUpdate` method on `functions.auth.user()`.  How do I check the user has updated their provider and get the email etc.

Comment: There is no onUpdate for Firebase Auth.  You will have to do this entirely on the client using data you control.  Please file a feature request for onUpdate, as it's a common request.  https://support.google.com/firebase/contact/support

Comment: @DougStevenson am I correct in assuming once you've linked the social provider i.e. google sign in to the anonymous account, you need to then sign the user in with that provider to retrieve the photoURL, email, etc... ?